# Solving Dual Problem using Simplex Method?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, simplex-method

Let's say I have a primal problem as follows:

```
(P) Max 2x1 + 3x2 + 5x3
s.t
x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 <= 8
x1 - 2x2 + 2x3 <=6
x>=0
```

Then we obtain the dual as follows:

```
(D) Min 8w1 + 6w2
s.t
w1 + w2 >= 2
2w1 - 2w2 >= 3
3w1 + 2w2 >= 5
w>=0
```

After obtaining the dual problem, when I try to apply Simplex method on the dual problem, I have realized that the table is already optimal which leads to the optimal objective value 0. But applying simplex to the primal problem, it is not possible to get the same solution. How is that possible? Is it not possible to apply Simplex method to the dual problem?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: Please show us ýour working by inputing your simplex tableau either with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27756/290189) or [Markdown syntax for tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32850/290189).

Comment: The optimal value of the dual cannot be $0$, since it wouldn´t fulfill the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal solutions are $x=(7,0.5,0)$ and $w=(1.75,0.25)$, both with objective value $15.5$.  Your dual formulation is correct.  Yes, you can apply the simplex method to the dual problem, but $0$ is not optimal.

Comment: How did your answer addresses OP's doubts about his observations from the simplex tableau?  How did you obtain your optimal values?  Please show us your working.